# Integrate Wordpress into node.js application

Tags: node.js, wordpress, installation, integration

I had a client, who required a real-time video chatting website. I've successfully completed the job using node.js. Now, the client is asking to install WordPress so he can, add or remove plugins (like SEO, visit counter) on his own, and **I don't know how to do it**.

So, how can install Wordpress in my site, so when the client visits **example.com** the chatting application loads, and when client visits **example.com/login** Wordpress Admin Dashboard is loaded.

Comment: Please go through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqKaZO9epHM),I hope that you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. You have a node application and when it routes to example.com/login that is where your wordpress application is placed (you have developed it locally or online so just copy those files to that route, it will load the index. You will need to have wordpress dependencies installed, or install them from the browser. It is important to remember you are essentially installing two sites under the same url prefix though.